# Boolean Equivalence using Karnaugh Maps

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

If I had two functions, where each letter represents a state:

- f(1) = CD + AB
- f(2) = AC + AD + BC

How could I find the minimum term that would need to be added to the second function to make the functions equivalent using Karnaugh maps?

I know how to minimise functions with Karnaugh maps, but this question has confused me.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is, that you are trying to find a function $f(3)$ (although this is a rather awkward notation for functions) such that

$$f(2) + f(3) = f(1)$$

or in other words you are searching

$$f(3) = f(1) + f(2) = CD + AB + AC+AD+BC$$

(the + there is the same as a -, since we are working with booleans) Now you should know how to minimize the right hand side.

Comment: Ah I see, now f(3) doesn't look like any function I've reduced using Karnaugh maps before. Usually the terms would be grouped and easily split up, e.g. f(x) = ABC + A'BC' this would allow me to split the terms into AB and C then work out the variation from there. However with CD + AB + AC + AD + BC I cannot see how I would split the terms then use a Karnaugh map to reduce the function.

Comment: It should work the same, just use brute force, calculate the truth table for the function, then fill in a the grid for a 4 variable karnaugh map and find the larger rectangles corresponding to smaller terms.

Comment: I'm still struggling, I should be able to do this but I simply can't. By a 4 variable Karnaugh map do you mean having the terms AB and CD (and all their iterations) for the column/row headers respectively? If so, how is this possible with the terms that have been given e.g. term: CD wouldn't correspond to any value from the AB columns.

Comment: You can just plug in the values into the formula. For examples for A=1,B=0,C=1,D=1 you end up with $f(3) = 1 + 0+1+1+0 = 1$ and so on for all combinations.

Comment: Right I'll give it a go now. Thanks.

Comment: That's only going to be false in one case, when ABCD are all 0, I don't see how that's going to help, sorry about my confusion. The question specifically asks to solve it using Karnaugh maps.